# Extract subsets of file1 with the same pattern of first column and by comparing the second column values with the file2

Tags: awk

File1

```
a   1
a   2
a   3
b   2
b   3
b   4
b   5
```

File2

```
2
4
3
1
```

output

```
a   1
a   2
a   3
```

From file1 "b" values are removed and "a" values only needs to be retained, since one of the "b" corresponding value in second column which is "5" from the file1 is not in the file2.

So, basically I need to make the subset of file1 based on the first column with the same pattern and make an index array with the corresponding second column values and search in the second file. If any value misses in the second file then I would like to discard the complete subset.

I could extract the lines which are matching the file1 2nd column values with the file2 1st column values. I am trying to figure out the creating subsets based on first column and the array index.

Temporarly, I did this with two simple steps:

First step:

```
awk '{print $1}' file1| sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//g'| sed 's/ /_/g'|sort > file1_modified.txt
output:
3_a
4_b
```

Second step: print lines of file1, if the file2 values are in the second column pf file1 and compare with the file1_modified.txt to get the matched lines then use the output to extract lines from file1

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($2 in a){print}' file2 file1|awk '{print $1}'| sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//g'| sed 's/ /_/g'|sort|comm -12 - file1_modified.txt| awk '{FS="_"}{print $2}'| grep -f - file1
output:
a   1
a   2
a   3
```

Hope I have explained it better way and would be helpfull if any one could provide some suggestions.

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Post your efforts into the question

Comment: Actually I found your description hard to understand. I think you mean "Remove all lines from `file1` with a first value that is in any line combined with a second value not contained in `file2`" -- Right?

Comment: Yup, that' is right @Philippos